# Is it Possible to Add A new property to Existing Interface When You Call the Interface?

Tags: c#

Let me preface by saying I am new to coding and C# is my first language. Just getting used to inheritance and interfaces. Consider this example:

```
public interface ITDXInput
    {
        ISCContext SCContext { get; set; }
        IToolContext ToolContext { get; set; }
    }
```

Which calls this Inteface:

```
public interface IToolContext
    {
        string LOT { get; set; }
        string TDX_MULTI_FILES { get; set; }
        string PROCESSING_START_TIME { get; set; }
        string PROCESSING_END_TIME { get; set; }
        string MEDIA_ORIGIN_LOCATION { get; set; }
        string MEDIA_ORIENTATION { get; set; }
        string MEDIA_AXIS_DIRECTION { get; set; }
    }
```

ITDXInput is referenced:

```
public class CIMTDXInput : ITDXInput
    {
        public ISCContext SCContext { get; set; }
        public ITestToolContext ToolContext { get; set; }
    }
```

ItoolContext is referenced in two places:

```
public class CIMToolContext : IToolContext
    {
        public string LOT { get; set; }
        public string TDX_MULTI_FILES { get; set; }
        public string PROCESSING_START_TIME { get; set; }
        public string PROCESSING_END_TIME { get; set; }
        public string RECIPE_NAME { get; set; }
        public string TOOL_IMAGE_PATH { get; set; }
        public string TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION { get; set; }
        public string MEDIA_ORIGIN_LOCATION { get; set; }
        public string MEDIA_ORIENTATION { get; set; }
        public string MEDIA_AXIS_DIRECTION { get; set; }
        public string WITHIN_UNIT_ORIGIN_LOCATION { get; set; }
        public string WITHIN_UNIT_AXIS_DIRECTION { get; set; }
    }
```

And here:

```
public class RMTToolContext : IToolContext
    {
        public string LOT { get; set; }
        public string TDX_MULTI_FILES { get; set; }
        public string PROCESSING_START_TIME { get; set; }
        public string PROCESSING_END_TIME { get; set; }
        public string MEDIA_ORIGIN_LOCATION { get; set; }
        public string MEDIA_ORIENTATION { get; set; }
        public string MEDIA_AXIS_DIRECTION { get; set; }
    }
```

Because of this when I try to run

```
Someclass{

public CIMTDXInput CimInput 
        {
            get { return (CIMTDXInput)base.TDXInput; }
        
        } 

protected override void PopulateValueMap()
        {
            ValueMap["#DATA.TOOL_CONTEXT.RECIPE_NAME#"] = CimInput.ToolContext.RECIPE_NAME;
            ValueMap["#DATA.TOOL_CONTEXT.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION#"] = CimInput.ToolContext.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION;

        }

}
```

It tells me IToolContext does not contain a definition for RECIPE_NAME and TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION

I was wondering if there is a way to modify IToolContext when I call it CIMTDXInput? If there is a way to extend ItoolContext for just that CIMTDXInput class?

This way I don't need to declare those additional fields for the root IToolContext Interface because the other tool RMTToolContext doesn't need those extra properties of RECIPE_NAME and TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION?

Unless there is a better way to handle these extra fields that CIMToolContext needs?

Comment: Fundamental misunderstanding of interfaces here. An interface defines that some implementing object has a minimum set of properties and operations and can hence be used by something willing to limit itself to only those operations. A car has a steering wheel, accelerator and brake. They are always in the same position relative to the driver, regardless the car model. They always do the same thing in every different car. My dad can drive any car he gets in because he knows when he presses the accelerator down the car moves. When he turns the wheel clockwise the car steers right. This is the ...

Comment: ... common interface of the car. My dad has absolutely no idea how to operate the sat nav of a Tesla or pop the hood of a Mustang; these are not a common part of the interface of all cars, and my dad is not willing to expand his knowledge on a case by case basis to cater for these differences. He just wants to get in a car, press the pedals and turn the wheels he knows about and have it act in the way he expects

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there is a way to modify IToolContext when I call it CIMTDXInput? If there is a way to extend ItoolContext for just that CIMTDXInput class?

Not exactly. You cannot modify the type definitions. Assuming you know *for sure* that the `IToolContext` you are dealing with is a `CIMTDXInput`, you can type cast it to the `CIMTDXInput` type. (This means it will be treated as a `CIMTDXInput` instead of a `IToolContext`.

**Be warned**, however, if you attempt to cast this `IToolContext` to `CIMToolContext` and it is not actually an instance of the `CIMToolContext` class, your program will throw an exception (error).

---

A safer way to do the same thing is to use the `is` operator to check that the `IToolContext` is actually a `CIMToolContext` instance.

This can be done as follows:

```cs
if (CimInput.ToolContext is CIMToolContext) {
    ValueMap["#DATA.TOOL_CONTEXT.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION#"] = (CIMToolContext)CimInput.ToolContext.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION;
}
```

or, slightly more concisely:

```cs
if (CimInput.ToolContext is CIMToolContext cimToolContext) {
    ValueMap["#DATA.TOOL_CONTEXT.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION#"] = cimToolContext.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION;
}
```

---

As a general rule, casting should be a last-ish resort. If possible, you should design your types so that it is unnecessary.

---

> Unless there is a better way to handle these extra fields that CIMToolContext needs?

I think for your case there might be. In your case, I think I might lean towards the use of [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) for a cleaner solution but this is a slightly more complex idea.

This would, however, allow you to do all of this without any typecasts.

```cs
public interface ITDXInput<TContext>
{
    ISCContext SCContext { get; set; }
    TContext ToolContext { get; set; }
}

public class CIMTDXInput : ITDXInput<CIMToolContext>
{
    public ISCContext SCContext { get; set; }
    public CIMToolContext ToolContext { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{

    public CIMTDXInput CimInput 
    {
        get { return base.TDXInput; }
    } 

    protected override void PopulateValueMap()
    {
        ValueMap["#DATA.TOOL_CONTEXT.RECIPE_NAME#"] = CimInput.ToolContext.RECIPE_NAME;
        ValueMap["#DATA.TOOL_CONTEXT.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION#"] = CimInput.ToolContext.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION;
    }

}
```

Comment: That is an interesting use of generics. Never seen that before. How would you then call functions that call the Interface ITDXInput. Such as a function with this signature:

CheckCIMTDXInput(ITDXInput input, TDX2KlarfResult result)

Comment: 2 possible ways off the top of my head. Either those functions are updated to use the generic interface _or_ you have the generic interface (in this case `ITDXInput<T>` extend `ITDXInput` (one of the two will need a name change))

Comment: So the new function signature would be: 
CheckCIMTDXInput <T>(ITDXInput<T> input, TDX2KlarfResult result) ?

Comment: Yep, that should work. Going to write up a fiddle with a working example, because there are a couple of ways (notable "where" generic constraint) that this might be able to be tuned to your needs.

Comment: ok, here are a few examples that can be run. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ig0Fl7

Comment: In the case you mentioned, `CheckCIMTDXInput`, I do wonder why you're using the most-generic interface for the `input` param (since the method name implies it only works with one type). Should this value ever by anything other than a `CIMTDXInput`?

Comment: I need to rename that function. I started exploring generic when I realized I needed to add new "tools" besides CIM. Like RMT. So that function will be renamed to CheckTDXInput. 

I have another quesition. How would I call a generic class/interface in a composition?

So instead of public ITDXInput TDXInput { get; set; }

How would I call the ITDXInput <generic> class in a composition or to initialize an object/property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245062/discussion-between-john-paul-r-and-datboydozy).

Comment: I have a new question that you might be able to help me with if you have time:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72398432/how-to-use-generic-delegate-to-access-derived-class-members