# How to use Generic Delegate to access Derived Class Members?

Tags: c#

Let me preface by saying I am new to coding and C# is my first language

I have a interface:

```
public interface ITDXInput <TSCContext, TContext, TWaferContainer> : ITDXInput
    {
        TSCContext SCContext { get; set; }
        TContext ToolContext { get; set; }
        TWaferContainer WaferContainer { get; set; }
    }
```

This class implements the interface:

```
public class CIMTDXInput : ITDXInput<CIMSCContext, CIMToolContext, CIMWaferContainer>
    {
        public CIMWaferContainer WaferContainer { get; set; }
        public CIMSCContext SCContext { get; set; }
        public CIMToolContext ToolContext { get; set; }
    }
```

The members of this class inherit from the following interfaces:

```
public class CIMSCContext : ISCContext
{
    public string PROCESSING_END_TIME { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string QUANTITY_IN { get; set; }
    public string LOT_OWNER { get; set; }
    public string FW_VERSION { get; set; }
 
}

public class CIMToolContext : IToolContext
{
    public string LOT { get; set; }
    public string TDX_MULTI_FILES { get; set; }
    public string PROCESSING_START_TIME { get; set; }
    public string WITHIN_UNIT_AXIS_DIRECTION { get; set; }
}

public class CIMWaferContainer : IWaferContainer
{
    public CIMWaferContext WaferContext = new CIMWaferContext();
    public List<CIMWaferImage> ImageList = new List<CIMWaferImage>();
    public List<CIMWaferDieResults> WaferResultList = new List<CIMWaferDieResults>();

}
```

I have a delegate handling class:

```
public class KlarfTemplateDelegateHandler
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Delegate> HandlerMap = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    public static Dictionary<string, Delegate> DefectListHandlerMap = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    delegate string TemplateDelegate<T,U,V>(ITDXInput<T, U, V> cimInput);
    delegate string DefectListTemplateDelegate(CIMTDXInput cimInput, List<CIMKlarfDefectList> list);

    static KlarfTemplateDelegateHandler()
    {
        HandlerMap["#DATA.TOOL_CONTEXT.PROCESSING_END_TIME_DATE#"] = new TemplateDelegate<ISCContext,IToolContext, IWaferContainer>(ProcessEndDate);
        HandlerMap["#DATA.TOOL_CONTEXT.PROCESSING_END_TIME_TIME#"] = new TemplateDelegate(ProcessEndTime);
        
    }


    private static string ProcessEndDate<T,U,V>(ITDXInput<T,U,V> cimInput)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(cimInput.ToolContext.PROCESSING_END_TIME);

        //return cimInput.CIMSCContext.PROCESSING_END_TIME.Split(' ')[0];
        return dateTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
    }
}
```

The issue is that for the function ProcessEndDate, it tells me that 'T' does not contain a definition for "PROCESSING_END_TIME_TIME". I tried to replace TSCContext inside ITDXInput with ISCContext as the generic for the ITDXInput's TSCContext but it's localized.

Is there anything I can do to be able to get the function to see that whatever ITDXInput I pass into the ProcessEndDate function will have the PROCESSING_END_TIME_TIME definition?

I am going through this exercise because I would like to reuse that delegatehandler class for other types of TDXInput

Comment: I believe it could be as simple as constraining your function like so: `private static string ProcessEndDate<T,U,V>(ITDXInput<T,U,V> cimInput) where U : ISCContext` perhaps you could give it a try  (because you have a lot of generic arguments there!)

Comment: @IVSoftware yes that was a typo. Indeed PROCESSING_END_TIME is part of ISContext. I have edited my question to take care of that. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to constrain the `ProcessEndDate` method. A minimal example of this would be to have this interface:

```
public interface ISCContext
{
    string PROCESSING_END_TIME { get; set; }
}
```

with two different classes that implement it:

```
public class ClassA : ISCContext
{
    public string PROCESSING_END_TIME { get; set; } = "A:" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
}


public class ClassB : ISCContext
{
    public string PROCESSING_END_TIME { get; set; } = "B:" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
}
```

To let the compiler know what to expect in a generic method, you would use the keyword `where` to make an interface constraint. For clarity, I made a new method with only 1 generic argument. You could, of course, have multiple arguments and corresponding constraints to define expectations for `T`, `U` and `V` but this gives you the basic idea.

```
private static void showProcessingEndTime<T>(T item) where T : ISCContext
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.PROCESSING_END_TIME);
}
```

Here's a Microsoft article explaining the many ways [Generic Type Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) may be used.

**Test code**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new ClassA();
    showProcessingEndTime(a);

    var b = new ClassB();
    showProcessingEndTime(b);
}
```

[image: Console output]

Comment: Well this is a good idea. Now I have a more complicated example. Is there anyway that I can send you this complicated example. I can modify my original question too. @IVSoftware

Comment: I suggest working this out in the format of the site which is very good. As a newer user, have you taken the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)? In particular, what helps for complicated questions is to boil them down to a [Minimum Reproducible Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Perhaps you'd like to edit your post?

Comment: Yep I read through that section. I have opened up a new question and tried my best to best convey the issue in as much minimal code as possible. Please have a look if you have time:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399464/derived-objected-cannot-be-converted-to-base-object-in-delegate-handler